# Rest API design - post and put to an ordered sub resource

Tags: rest

I am designing and building an API for recipes. I am happy with crud operations on the recipe resource.
For example

```
GET api/recipe - returns all recipes
POST api/recipe (with json recipe in body) - creates a new recipe
GET api/recipe/23 - returns recipe 23
PUT api/recipe/23 (with json recipe in body) - update recipe
DELETE api/recipe/23 - deletes the recipe
```

I am struggling with the sub resource of Instruction i.e. api/recipe/23/instruction specifically the post and put.

```
GET api/recipe/23/instruction - returns all recipe 23 instructions
POST api/recipe/23/instruction (with json list of instructions) - adds a new list of instructions
PUT api/recipe/23/instruction (with json list of instructions) - replaces list of instructions

GET api/recipe/23/instruction/1 - returns the first instruction
POST api/recipe/23/instruction/2 - inserts an instruction at that location
PUT api/recipe/23/instruction/1 (with json instruction in body) - updates that instruction
DELETE api/recipe/23/instruction/1 - deletes the instruction
```

Here are my questions

1. Should you be able to POST a list? If so as the instructionId is going to be the order it appears, should the instructionId be populated in the POST?
2. Should you be able to PUT a new list of Instructions to replace them?
3. Should you be able to POST to a specific instructionId to insert an item in the order? Would the response just be the URI or the full list?
4. If there are 6 Instructions and a DELETE is done on Instruction 2 is it OK to reorder the instructions? If so what should the response be? The new list of instructions?

For me the PUT of an instruction list doesn't feel quite right along with the POST to a specific instructionId.

Comment: In POST you are litterally free to do whatever you want as the semantics here are defined by the implementor of the serivce. Whether you return content on POST requests or not is some implementation detail. In general it is good advice to return the stored payload to inform the client on the current state of a resource. If you created a new resource you should return a 201 created with a Location header pointing to the new resource. PUT actually has the semantics of replacing the current state with the one given in the requests payload, it isn't intended for partial updates though!

Comment: You don't actually use the HTTP operation DELETE to remove something within a resource. According to [the HTTP spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) DELETE actually only removes the link between the URL and the resource. So not even a guarantee is given that the data is actually deleted at all. If you need to remove certain parts of a resource either use PUT and send the updated representation to the server or use PATCH and instruct the server to remove the requested element. If you need to remove items within a collection delete the respective resource then